# "The patch does not apply to Tfs version 14.102.25423.0" when trying to apply the patch 7 on TFS 2015 v4.2

Tags: tfs, version, patch, tfs-2015

I am trying to install the tfs2015.4.2patch7 on my server.
I found the .exe of the patch [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2015-update4-vs).

When I execute it as administrator on the server, I get the following error message:

```
Logging to 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs\Patch_2022-04-26_09-21-28.log

Checking SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\14.0 to see if TFS is installed

Found InstallPath: F:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\
Found InstallVersion: 14.102.25423.0
Could not find Patch version in registry, no patches installed.
The Application Tier is configured.
The search Tier is not configured.
The proxy Tier is not configured
This patch does not apply to Tfs version 14.102.25423.0.

Hit Enter to Exit
```

I don't see what is wrong, and why the patch could not be applied, since it has been released precisely for this version of TFS.
Could you please help me?

Comment: You may have to update to Update 4.2 before you apply 4.2 patch 7. Try that.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I'm already updated to 4.2. I think the problem is that I need to first install the patch  2 before the 7. But I can't find this patch, only the 7 is downloadable.